# Stuck with cudf in WSL2 - Installed all dependencies but after loading it, its not working at all

Tags: python, wsl-2, rapids, cudf

Im using WSL2 and for some reason cudf.pandas is not using my gpu at all, in fact it stays at 0% usage with large datasets. I've installed rapids and cuda running the following codes succesfully:

```
%load_ext cudf.pandas
import pandas as pd
print(pd)

<module 'pandas' (ModuleAccelerator(fast=cudf, slow=pandas))>
```

```
import cudf
print(cudf.Series([1, 2, 3]))

0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Also I this are my specs when runing nvidia-smi:

[image]

And the cuda toolkit **nvcc --version**:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0
```

EDIT:

I installed nvtop as suggested an noticed the following error when runing the line %load_ext cudf.pandas:
[image]

Comment: Can you share more about the pandas functions that you're testing? While `cudf.pandas` accelerates a large portion of the pandas API, not all features are supported. If a feature is not supported by `cudf.pandas`, it will fall back to the CPU for processing. It's possible that you are testing a pandas function (or function argument) that isn't supported. On the positive side, your cudf installation does appear to be working correctly, and `cudf.pandas` appears to be activated based on the `ModuleAccelerator` info.

Comment: Hi Bradley, is there a chance that df.apply is not supported like you said ? Not seeing much of an improvement .

Comment: cuDF supports a limited set of features from `df.apply`. It's likely that your apply function is not supported, so it's falling back to CPU.

You can see more about the supported operations/types at this link: https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cudf/stable/user_guide/guide-to-udfs/ and in the cuDF docs for DataFrame.apply.

Answer (score 0):

First, your screen shot shows 13% GPU Utilization.  Congrats on capturing that, as it is sometimes hard to get a number other than 0.  Unless you're crunching GBs, many operations complete before you hit enter on `nvidia-smi`.  When no processing is happening than instant, your GPU utilization will be 0%.  However, your memory utilization size will increase.  It says you have 1196 MiB used out of 12288MiB, which says something has happened on the GPU.

A better way to check GPU utilization is historical graphing.  As you are in WSL2, a great, built-in Windows tools that does this well is Task Manager's Performance tab.  In Ubuntu, a great tool to use, if using CLI, is [nvtop](https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop).  It will graph historical usage. Finally, in docker, or jupyter hub, NVIDIA has NVDashboard integrations for jupyter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I might have been runing something else on the background, but I have done multiple test, and its taking the same time as normal pandas. In the other side, I installed nvtop as you suggested and noticed that after running the line %load_ext cudf.pandas it shows an error 

"nvtop: ./src/extract_gpuinfo.c:205: gpuinfo_populate_process_infos: Assertion `devices[i].processes[j].gpu_memory_percentage <= 100' failed."

I'll update the screenshot to the post.

Comment: Ok I found my error. I was trying to read the file from the c drive instad of wsl itself:

pd.read_csv(/mnt/c/file.csv) instad of moving it inside of linux.

In the other hand I still don't now why nvtop crashes when I load cudf.

Comment: That's interesting that reading from host instead of within the container would cause that much of a slow down.  There may be a larger issue at play.  But please use Windows Task Manager for this.  The rest was in case you or someone else later decided to go full ubuntu install (nvtop) or use docker/jupyter hub (NVDashboard) and wanted to also graph GPU utilization.